# Supposedly “broken” laptop battery seemingly works fine with OS is restored. Is my battery bad?

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, battery

I am working on a PC with Windows 7 starter edition. The PC is extremely slow. Nobody has ever formatted it since first use (in 2011).

The battery was marked as broken by the OS, not possible to be charged and if unplugged, the PC was immediately shutdown, just as if it was powered off with no battery at all.

After the OS restore was completed, the battery was back on: The first charge went OK and it also now stays on unplugged for 1h with no problems.

Can anyone explain what happend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some chargers *calculate* the state of charge of a battery rather than *measuring* it, and retain that information in Flash RAM or on disk; by reinstalling the OS, you inadvertently reset the stored battery state (a more accurate charger has current and voltage limits but also measures the *rate* of voltage change and stops charging when dV/dt approaches a limit).

Even small appliances have the same issue; our robot vacuum has, on occasion, refused to charge until the battery is unplugged and the vacuum memory is reset.

See http://www.brighthub.com/computing/hardware/articles/50844.aspx, http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19451836 and http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201575 for reference on resetting charging. BTW, **do not completely drain Li-ion batteries, as some sites recommend, as that can damage them.**

Please let me know if this answers the question.